# Double-entry Schengen visa, leaving the Schengen area for a month and coming back

Tags: schengen, multiple-entry

I am planning on getting a double-entry Schengen visa from the Italian embassy. My plan is as follows:

- 4 days in Germany (end of November).
- 14 days in Italy (start of January).

After my time in Germany I will be leaving the Schengen area to go back to my own country. Then later I'll fly into Italy. The reason I want a double-entry instead of two single-entry visas is because my University is funding my time in Italy and I require proof of visa a month in advance, something I will not be able to do due to time constraints.

Question:

Is it possible for me to get a double-entry Schengen visa since I am staying outside the Schengen area for over a month between entries? Will this be a problem? Any document I can provide to justify my circumstances?